# Method "OpenBinaryStream" does not exist reading a file from SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I have some code that runs fine on a SP2013 server that opens a SharePoint file and processess it as a memory stream.  I need to have the same working for a 2010 server.

Using the same code and the most recent client and runtime DLLs I am able to connect to the server and the library but I get an error "*Method "OpenBinaryStream" does not exist*" When the following line executes:

```
ClientResult<Stream> fileContents = file.OpenBinaryStream();
```

I have checked its [supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfileversion.openbinarystream(v=office.14).aspx) in 2010. It shows up in intellisense and doesn't have a problem compiling.

Here is the full code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string serverURL = "http://SP2010";
        string libraryName = "Documents";
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(serverURL);

        List myList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
        CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
        ListItemCollection items = myList.GetItems(query);

        // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
        {
            string fileText = string.Empty;

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = listItem.File;

            context.Load(file);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            string fileUrl = file.ServerRelativeUrl;
            Console.WriteLine(fileUrl);


                ClientResult<Stream> fileContents = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                MemoryStream fileContentStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                fileContents.Value.CopyTo(fileContentStream);
                fileText += extractor.TextFromTextFile(fileContentStream);
```

Any ideas very much appreciated.

Thanks
Bren

Answer (score 2):

It does [not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file_methods(v=office.14).aspx) appear to be supported in `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` in SharePoint 2010. The link you provided to MSDN was for `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`.

Comment: Sergey reread the original post, they're using the client namespace, which lacks that method. You posted the SSOM method.

Comment: I apologize for inconvenience, have posted the wrong link. Removed my old to not to mislead. [OpenBinaryDirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarydirect(v=office.14)) method is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the pointers, here is the working code which uses the OpenBinaryDirect and pushes it into a memory stream.

```
FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl);

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var buf = new byte[1024 * 16];
                    int byteSize;
                    while ((byteSize = fileInfo.Stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Write(buf, 0, byteSize);
                    }

                    fileText += extractor.TextFromDOCX(ms);
                    Console.WriteLine(fileText);
```

Comment: Please make sure to mark this as an answer when you're able!

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else scratching there head ... this can be done using the client library but  OpenBinaryDirect is static I was trying to call it on the instance so I couldn't find it